# Adding continuous border to only header and footer of table

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I would like a table where some cells have broken borders and others have continuous borders. For example, here is the html for a four column, 12 row table:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th id="blank_cell"></th> <!-- blank -->
            <th>first_c</th>
            <th>second_c</th>
            <th>third_c</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>row one</th>
            <td>1,1</td>
            <td>1,2</td>
            <td>1,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row two</th>
            <td>2,1</td>
            <td>2,2</td>
            <td>2,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row three</th>
            <td>3,1,</td>
            <td>3,2</td>
            <td>3,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row four</th>
            <td>4,1</td>
            <td>4,2</td>
            <td>4,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row five</th>
            <td>5,1</td>
            <td>5,2</td>
            <td>5,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row six</th>
            <td>6,1</td>
            <td>6,2</td>
            <td>6,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row seven</th>
            <td>7,1</td>
            <td>7,2</td>
            <td>7,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row eight</th>
            <td>8,1</td>
            <td>8,2</td>
            <td>8,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row nine</th>
            <td>9,1</td>
            <td>9,2</td>
            <td>9,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row ten</th>
            <td>10,1</td>
            <td>10,2</td>
            <td>10,3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>End</th>
            <td>e_one</td>
            <td>e_two</td>
            <td>e_three</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I would like the thead cells to have a continuous border along the bottom (except for the first, blank cell), whilst maintaining a broken border on the other rows.
Here is some CSS, it creates broken borders along the bottom of the rows (except the leftmost cells of each row).

```
body {
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    color:#111111;
}
table {
    width:450px;
}

td,th {
    padding:7px 10px 10px 10px;
}

thead th {
    border-bottom:4px solid #111111;
}

tbody th {
    border-left:2px solid #111111;
    border-right:4px solid #111111;
}

tbody td {
    border-bottom:2px solid #111111;
}

th {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    word-spacing:0.3em;
    text-align:left;
}

#blank_cell {
    border:none;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color:#c3e6e5;
}
```

I want the very first row - the header row - to have a continuous, unbroken line, whereas I want the others to remain as they are (i.e. broken). All I can find, so far, is styling that is applied to the whole table: for example, I can't seem to collapse borders or set zero spacing on just the cells in the thead part of the table. So if I make the borders continuous, it is applied to the entire table.

Comment: Post a picture of what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to put it in two different tables, the first containing the content of your `tr.header`, with `cellspacing="0"` and the second with the default value.  However, that means that you'll have to add CSS to keep the width's consistent, and that may be a problem depending on what you are putting into the table(s).  If that isn't a problem, here is the code with all columns set to 25% width:

([and a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/rfswohah/6/))

```
<body>
<table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th id="blank_cell"></th> <!-- blank -->
            <th>first_c</th>
            <th>second_c</th>
            <th>third_c</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>row one</th>
            <td>1,1</td>
            <td>1,2</td>
            <td>1,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row two</th>
            <td>2,1</td>
            <td>2,2</td>
            <td>2,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row three</th>
            <td>3,1,</td>
            <td>3,2</td>
            <td>3,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row four</th>
            <td>4,1</td>
            <td>4,2</td>
            <td>4,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row five</th>
            <td>5,1</td>
            <td>5,2</td>
            <td>5,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row six</th>
            <td>6,1</td>
            <td>6,2</td>
            <td>6,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row seven</th>
            <td>7,1</td>
            <td>7,2</td>
            <td>7,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row eight</th>
            <td>8,1</td>
            <td>8,2</td>
            <td>8,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row nine</th>
            <td>9,1</td>
            <td>9,2</td>
            <td>9,3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>row ten</th>
            <td>10,1</td>
            <td>10,2</td>
            <td>10,3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>End</th>
            <td>e_one</td>
            <td>e_two</td>
            <td>e_three</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</body>




body {
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    color:#111111;
}
table {
    width:450px;
}

td,th {
    padding:7px 10px 10px 10px;
}

thead th {
    border-bottom:4px solid #111111;
}

tbody th {
    border-left:2px solid #111111;
    border-right:4px solid #111111;
}

tbody td {
    border-bottom:2px solid #111111;
    width: 25%;
}

th {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    word-spacing:0.3em;
    text-align:left;
    width: 25%;
}

#blank_cell {
    border:none;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color:#c3e6e5;
}
```